# No function found for key: IF: Source Lightning

Tags: lightning

I'm trying to conditionally display the title of page based on a Boolean variable.

```
<aura:attribute name="isAvailable" type="Boolean" default="False" description="Boolean to display header." /> 


<c:myComponent pageTitle="{!IF(v.isAvailable,$Label.label1,$Label.label2)}" pageSubheading="{!$Label.subheadinglabel}}" hasBorderBottom="true" />
```

It throws an error saying `"No function found for key: IF: Source "`

We were able to successfully do this in regular apex tags in VF page. How can i get it to work on lightning?

Comment: You need a function in your controller for "isAvailable" before this will work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not <s>`IF`</s> try with small letters `if`

```
<c:myComponent pageTitle="{!if(v.isAvailable,$Label.label1,$Label.label2)}" pageSubheading="{!$Label.subheadinglabel}}" hasBorderBottom="true" />
```